# Swift 3: Reading content of folder?

Tags: swift, directory

There are a lot of questions and answers belonging how to read the contents of a directory. Unfortunatly none of them I get to work with Swift 3.0. Is there any update, which is running right now?

(Most of them get errors by the compiler and if I correct everything the way the compiler sugguested, I get a runtime error later on!) :-(

Reference to linked solution:
This does not show any sub folder files like "while let url = enumerator.nextObject() as? URL" did. Is the headline misleading or do I need different function or additional parameters?

Comment: Thank you, I didn't see the update. Looks like what I searched for!

Comment: This does not show any sub folder files like "while let url = enumerator.nextObject() as? URL" did. Is the headline misleading or do I need different function or additional parameters?

Comment: I could not paste the code I used, bc. it is marked as duplicate (which is not). Send me a note and I send you the code. Main part is:
let directoryEnumerator = FileManager().enumerator(at: directoryURL, includingPropertiesForKeys: resourceKeys, options: [.skipsHiddenFiles], errorHandler: nil)!

    for case let fileURL as NSURL in directoryEnumerator {
        guard let resourceValues = try? fileURL.resourceValues(forKeys: resourceKeys),
            let isDirectory = resourceValues[URLResourceKey.isDirectoryKey] as? Bool
            else {
                continue
        }